# How I can know in my Android Unity game, when my local server is down?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, server

I'm developing a game for Android and I'm using a local server for the database. I need to know if there is a way to know when my server is down (for example if my internet provider company has a network problem and my server gets out from the network).

I use the [Unity web request sending form](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html) to do things with the database.

And I already tried to check it in " **if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)** ", but it does not work.

```
 IEnumerator Upload() {
    List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
    formData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection("field1=foo&field2=bar") );
    formData.Add( new MultipartFormFileSection("my file data", "myfile.txt") );

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://www.my-server.com/myform", formData);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
    }
}
```

There is a way or maybe it is not possible?

Comment: `but it does not work.` ... Allow me to doubt that .. you should get a `responseCode = 404` leading to `isHttpError` ... you could instead use e.g. `if(www.responseCode >= 400)`

Comment: Thank you derHugo, it works how you said!!